# How do I remove trailing slash in redirected URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this redirect for specific URLs to remove the `.php` extension and it works, but adds trailing slash at the end of each redirected URL. How do I remove that trailing slash only from the redirected URLs in this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(about|contact)(\.php)?$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(about|contact)/$ $1.php [END,QSA,NC]
```

I tried adding this rule `RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]` additionally, but I get an error on those same pages.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(about|contact)(\.php)?$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
> -----------------------------------------^
> ```

Because you are appending a trailing slash here ^

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(about|contact)/$ $1.php [END,QSA,NC]
> ----------------------------^
> ```

However, you are also *expecting* a trailing slash in the following rule (above). So you can't simply remove the trailing slash in the first rule without also modifying the second rule.

These rules are focused on enforcing a trailing slash. To avoid the trailing slash you need to change both rules (not add another rule) to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(about|contact)\.php$ /$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(about|contact)$ $1.php [END]
```

If you are using the `END` flag on the 2nd (rewrite) rule then the `RewriteCond` directive on the first rule that checked the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not required.

Since you are no longer appending a trailing slash, the `.php` extension on the first rule should *not* be optional (as you had it originally). Otherwise, you will get a redirect-loop.

You should avoid the `NC` flag on the second rule as this promotes *duplicate content* (but you aren't using this on the first rule anyway). The `QSA` flag on this rule is not required.

You don't need the `RewriteBase` directive here and should be omitted.

To clarify, you should be linking to `/about` and `/contact` (no `.php` extension) in your internal links.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That worked the way i need it!

Comment: @businezz That's great, you're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" (grey/green checkmark below the voting arrows) to remove the question from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Thanks, much appreciated. :)